# Whats wrong with this reducer

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would expect the final result should have the value.

"Error: Invalid UpdatableBy type got heLlo1"

Instead it  doesn't even print any console messages or get into the reduce function. I can do this using foreach but thought of trying this using reduce method.

the final output in t  is "heLl01"

```js
pobject = {
  UpdatableBy: ["heLlo1"]
}
let t;
let updatedUpdatableBy = []
t = pobject.UpdatableBy.reduce((allerrors, val) => {
  console.log(allerrors)
  console.log(val)
  if (typeof val !== "string") {
    allerrors += "Error: Invalid UpdatableBy data type got " + typeof val
  } else {
    if (val.toUpperCase() == "HELLO") {
      updatedUpdatableBy.push("Hello")
    } else if (val.toUpperCase() == "HI") {
      updatedUpdatableBy.push("Hi")
      console.log("Hi")
    } else if (val.toUpperCase() == "HOW") {
      updatedUpdatableBy.push("How")
      console.log("How")
    } else {
      allerrors += "Error: Invalid UpdatableBy type got " + val
      console.log(allerrors)
    }
  }
  return allerrors
});
console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

> initialValue [Optional]
>
> Value to use as the first argument to the
>   first call of the callback. **If no initial value is supplied, the first
>   element in the array will be used.** Calling reduce on an empty array
>   without an initial value is an error.

So you need to pass the initialValue to append to, in your case is an empty string.

```js
pobject = {
  UpdatableBy: ["heLlo1"]
}
let t;
let updatedUpdatableBy = []
t = pobject.UpdatableBy.reduce((allerrors, val) => {
  if (typeof val !== "string") {
    allerrors += "Error: Invalid UpdatableBy data type got " + typeof val
  } else {
    if (val.toUpperCase() == "HELLO") {
      updatedUpdatableBy.push("Hello")
    } else if (val.toUpperCase() == "HI") {
      updatedUpdatableBy.push("Hi")
      console.log("Hi")
    } else if (val.toUpperCase() == "HOW") {
      updatedUpdatableBy.push("How")
      console.log("How")
    } else {
      allerrors += "Error: Invalid UpdatableBy type got " + val
    }
  }
  return allerrors
}, "");
console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reducer's accumulator needs to have a value to start appending to:
`[].reduce((acc, next) => {}, defaultAcc)`
In this case that would be `""`

```js
pobject = {
  UpdatableBy: ["heLlo1"]
}
let t;
let updatedUpdatableBy = []
t = pobject.UpdatableBy.reduce((allerrors, val) => {
  if (typeof val !== "string") {
    allerrors += "Error: Invalid UpdatableBy data type got " + typeof val
  } else {
    if (val.toUpperCase() == "HELLO") {
      updatedUpdatableBy.push("Hello")
    } else if (val.toUpperCase() == "HI") {
      updatedUpdatableBy.push("Hi")
      console.log("Hi")
    } else if (val.toUpperCase() == "HOW") {
      updatedUpdatableBy.push("How")
      console.log("How")
    } else {
      allerrors += "Error: Invalid UpdatableBy type got " + val
    }
  }
  return allerrors
  // here
}, "");
console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array has only 1 element, and there's no `initialValue` argument to `reduce()`, it doesn't bother calling the function, it simply returns that single value. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b):

> If the array has only one element (regardless of position) and no `initialValue` is provided, or if `initialValue` is provided but the array is empty, the solo value will be returned *without calling* `callback`.

This is because the function is supposed to combine the array element with the accumulated result from previous iterations. If there's only one element, there's no accumulated result to combine it with. `initialValue` is a default to use for that on the first iteration, but if that's not supplied, it can't call the function at all.

Since you're accumulating the results by concatenating them into a string, you can use `""` as the `initialValue` argument.